# How to multiply two vector and get a matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

In numpy operation, I have two vectors, let's say vector A is 4X1, vector B is 1X5, if I do AXB, it should result a matrix of size 4X5.

But I tried lot of times, doing many kinds of reshape and transpose, they all either raise error saying not aligned or return a single value.

How should I get the output product of matrix I want?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Normal matrix multiplication works as long as the vectors have the right shape.  Remember that `*` in Numpy is *elementwise multiplication*, and matrix multiplication is available with `numpy.dot()` (or with the `@` operator, in Python 3.5)

```
>>> numpy.dot(numpy.array([[1], [2]]), numpy.array([[3, 4]]))
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

This is called an "outer product."  You can get it using plain vectors using `numpy.outer()`:

```
>>> numpy.outer(numpy.array([1, 2]), numpy.array([3, 4]))
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using numpy.

First, make sure you have two vectors. For example, `vec1.shape = (10, )` and `vec2.shape = (26, )`; in numpy, row vector and column vector are the same thing.

Second, you do `res_matrix = vec1.reshape(10, 1) @ vec2.reshape(1, 26) ;`.

Finally, you should have: `res_matrix.shape = (10, 26)`.

numpy documentation says it will deprecate `np.matrix()`, so better not use it.

Answer (score 3):

Function [`matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) (since numpy 1.10.1) works fine:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
b = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],])

ab = np.matmul(a, b)
print (ab)
print(ab.shape)
```

You have to declare your vectors right. The first has to be a list of lists of one number (this vector has to have columns in one row), and the second - a list of list (this vector has to have rows in one column) like in above example.

Output:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1]
 [2 2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4 4]]

(4, 5)
```