# Get access index of a 2D array element built from 2 x 1D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following `prior_total` built from `prior_fish` array and `np.arange(5)` with `num_prior_loop=50`

```
# Declare prior array
prior_start = 1
prior_end = 5
prior_fish = np.logspace(prior_start,prior_end,num_prior_loop)
# Prior total
prior_total = np.stack([prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)])
```

How to get access to `prior_total[i,j]`, I mean `i` for the i-th element of `prior_fish` and `j` for the j-element of np.aranage(5) ?

I tried : `prior_total[i,j]` and `prior_total([[[0,i],[1,j]]]` but this doesn't work.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: prior_total[0,i], prior_total[1,j]

Comment: You are declaring prior_fish twice, so you can remove the first one

Comment: We already showed you in the previous question that you cannot `stack` 50 and 5 element arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = np.logspace(1,5,5)
b = np.arange(5)
c = np.stack([a.T, b])
```

`c[i,j]` returns a single element, at col `i` row `j`

`c[0,i], c[1,j]` returns two elements, the `i`th element of `a` and the `j`th element of `b`

Comment: This doesn't work since the number of rows and columns is different, how can I do ?

Comment: `prior_total = np.stack([prior_fish.T, np.arange(5)])` produces an error :  **raise ValueError('all input arrays must have the same shape')
ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape**

Comment: `num_prior_loop` is equal to `50` in my case

Comment: `np.arange(num_prior_loop)`, a and b should have the same length at index 0, check this link https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html

Comment: thanks but I just want to concatenate 2 arrays to build a 50x5 2D array

Comment: That is not possible with concatenate. Do you want 5x your prior fish? or a dot product with prior fish with arange(5)? `np.dot(a[None,:], b[:,None])`, you can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28578302/how-to-multiply-two-vector-and-get-a-matrix

Comment: if you want 5x prior_fish, make `b = np.ones(5)`

Comment: Thanks for your help